# Xaml and docking

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this XAML:

```
<Window .....>
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">.....</StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="200" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">....</StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The idea is the second `StackPanel` to be always on the bottom of the windows and the first `StackPanel`to be always on the top of the window and to take any acces space (i.e. stretch to the second `StackPanel`), but I cannot seem to achieve this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching the position of the two `StackPanels` and add `LastChildFill="True"` to your `DockPanel`:

```
<Window .....>
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Height="200" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">....</StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">.....</StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```